# Can't connect to Dynamics CRM server after installing Developer Extensions

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

After installing [Dynamics CRM & 365 Developer Extensions](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=JLattimer.DynamicsCRMDeveloperExtensions) I can't connect to Dynamics server (CRM online). When I disable this extension - all is ok. But I need to use two extensions (this and Microsoft Developer Extensions) in my project. What's the problem? Can this extension conflict with Microsoft Developer Extension?

[image]